# php-ews-master / response error

Tags: php, curl, libcurl, soap-client

I'm trying to use php-ews-master to connect to exchange server, and I'm struggling from a while.

With **CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1** I'm getting the error :

- Problem (3) in the Chunked-Encoded data.

If I modify to **CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_0** I got a response from the server but the response has a lot of added characters (I suppose these are because the chunked response???) and for this reason it's not a valid xml file.

The code I'm trying to use :

```
$headers = array(
 'Method: POST',
 'Connection: Keep-Alive',
 'User-Agent: PHP-SOAP-CURL',
 'Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8',
 'SOAPAction: "'.$action.'"',
 );
$this->ch = curl_init($location);
curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, $this->validate);
curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, $this->validate);
curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request);
curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_NTLM);
curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $this->user.':'.$this->password);*

$response = curl_exec($this->ch);
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
If anybody facing the same problem just add this line :

curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);